# typo3 8.7 images resize does not work properly

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

In my new typo3 8.7.22 installation the image crop does not work correctly. Images are only shown with a width of 600 px.

I set these constants:

```
styles.content.imgtext.maxWInText = 1200
styles.content.imgtext.layoutKey = data
styles.content.imgtext.linkWrap.width = 800
styles.content.loginform.pid = 0
styles.content.imgtext.maxW = 1200
```

What is my issue in this case?

imagemagic is installed and activated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: also tried this: `styles.content.IMAGE.maxW = 1200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution right after posting

solution is: `styles.content.textmedia.maxW = 1200`

Answer (score 1):

The content element (CE) with text and image has had some renames and restructures in the last versions of TYPO3.
And there was a change from CSC (css_styled_content), where the rendering was fully based on typoscript, to FSC (fluid_styled_content) with fluid based rendering.

Since ever `imgtext` got it's image rendering from the CE `image`, adapted for the usage in combination.
As the rendering was (nearly) identical to `image` if there is no text, in newer versions the CE `image` was deleted.

Then there was the enhancement for media which results in a new name `textmedia`.

In the same way the former field `images` got some renames. (`media`, `assets`)

Dependend on your current rendering package you might need some adaptions in CE name and field for pictures (and/or videos)